# Generate FedAuth cookie from MSAL Token

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-msal

We are using MSAL library for Authentication and it generates access token and refresh token which we have access to. Once successful login happens we want to open share point url using the session of the user which is already established.Is there a way to obtain Fedauth, rtfa cookies from token that got generated using MSAL library?

Comment: I would bet 100 bucks the answer is "NO" but subscribed to your question )

Comment: BTW if you need those to display profile (or other) images or files from SharePoint (like me) then there is a workaround - you could use graph API to get the same file in the SharePoint using graph token (the one you get with MSAL, that is). I.e. you could implement a "fallback" for image ("onerror") or file, and if direct SP link fails you can load the same using the graph API using your token.

Comment: Thanks @Nikolay..when searching for a work around most of them showed SAML approach for login instead of MSAL with Binary token and sending wa sigin api sharepoint which gets the rtfa and fedAuth token